# xampp não carrega javascript

Tags: javascript, xampp, localhost, carregamento

Tive que reinstalar o xampp, mas agora não carrega mais o javascript não sei por que, alguém tem uma ideia?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: veja como fica tudo bagunçado, como neste caso]

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Consegui resolver o problema era realmente o link do jquery. Quando o amigo falou para colocar o link do jquery em cima eu coloquei o antigo e não funcionou e eu fiz isto por que antes estava funcionando. Então comentei o link antigo e coloquei o novo em cima e funcionou, como vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo ficou assim.
[image: configuração de códigos javascript]

Comment: no console do navegador, apresenta algum erro ?

Comment: tem alguns vou colocar lá no post original

Comment: pronto coloquei

Comment: Incluiu o jquery no código ?

Comment: Tem jquery no site mas não em tudo

Comment: Não. Você incluiu o script que carrega o jquery ? Aparentemente o erro que está dando é referente a falta do jquery

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81853/discussion-between-user4451-and-pedro-augusto).

Answer (score 0):

User!

Poderia adicionar essa linha de código no header.php do seu site (***OU NO HEADER DA PÁGINA***)
Recomendo colocar esse código antes de qualquer outro javascript no header

***(Abaixo do titulo do site/página por exemplo)***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: vou ver se é isso

Comment: Na verdade não está faltando não, tem um include no final da página escrito scripts onde eu deixo todo os códigos javascripts, inclusive esse que vc mandou ai. Ainda não tenho ideia do que seja isto

Comment: Instalei o wampServer e também continua da mesma maneira, agora fiquei encucado

Comment: Com o navegador Google Chrome faça o seguinte procedimento:
Abra o seu site, aperta CTRL + SHIFT + I
Dê um F5 e veja se retorna algum erro que se refere a JavaScript, se possível, tire um print e upe no imgur pra que eu possa analisar

Comment: Heathcliff está ai o link https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/3y5434563-jpg-02687e7e-453c-40fd-b1ec-356ecdf9035c

Comment: Então, mano, ai tá dizendo que não tem javascript nenhum na página, se possível coloca os scripts no header do site pfv? :/

Comment: então, eu já coloquei não adianta em nada, fica o mesmo erro, veja na imagem a estrutura que eu uso https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/3y5434563-jpg-1e796806-983e-4a1c-9a5d-01629828be67

Comment: sempre usei esta estrutura nunca tive este problema ai, por isso recorro a vcs, não sei o que pode ser já pesquisei em vários lugares e não achei solução

Comment: Já tentou por o link direto ali ao invés do "js/seuarquivo.js" por "//seusite.com/js/seuarquivo.js" pra ver se você não está simplesmente errando o caminho do arquivo?